# How to order data from database by user choice

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Say i have this table :

```
---------+----------
name     | id
---------+----------
apple    | 1
orange   | 2
book     | 3
notebook | 4
textboo  | 5
phone    | 6
```

if the user want to sort this table as he want .. 
not order them as id or name .. order them as he want to show them ..

How to make something like that ?

Can we do them by java or jquery or something else

if user want to display **orange | 2** then  **phone    | 6**
then the other values or want to display  **notebook | 4** first then other values how we can control something like that ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what exactly you mean by **order them as he want to show them**. A couple of examples will be handy.

Comment: I edited the post to explain more .. check it

Comment: do you want to save the user ordered the table in frontend?

Comment: `order by case when name = 'orange' then 0 when name = 'phone' then 1 else 2 end`

Comment: @Shifter - If you want to store the user preference, you can add an additional column of seq number.

Comment: Ya i want to save the user order in table .. also i want to enable him to edit them if he want later
@nikhil ya that fine for me .. but which values to add ?!

Comment: @Shifter - You can add a new column let us say `sequence`. Then as per your user preference give it a value. As per your example, row with orange will have value 1 and row with phone will have value 2 and so on.

Comment: very good this give me an idea .. thanks alot

Comment: See FIELD() http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have multiple users you will need to create a new table where you will save each user's sort order preferences.

```
---------+-------------------
item_id     | user_id | sort
---------+------------------
1           | 1       | 2
2           | 1       | 1
3           | 1       | 3
```

After that you can easily use `ORDER BY` in your query to fetch the order chosen by the user based on his `user_id`. If you're looking for `user_id` = 1, the following query should work:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` t1 
     LEFT JOIN `preferences_table` PT ON PT.item_id = t1.id 
     WHERE user_id = 1 
     ORDER BY PT.sort ASC
```